# How do i refresh Perforce GUI using perforce command?

Tags: perforce

I have automated some p4 works like creating CL, deleting CL, syncing, branching with Perl. But I am facing a small problem when I create or delete a CL using P4 command (i.e. I create a CL using p4 command, it is created successfully. However, when I go to p4win I am not able to see the newly created change list until I refresh the view. Is there any p4 command available which will refresh the P4Win ).

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using something like AutoIt: http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: I haven't tried this yet.. But, it makes sense .. I will try this out...Thank you Bryan ...